# Angular.js, cancel ng-click event

Tags: javascript, events, angularjs

I have this piece of html

```
<button ui:confirm ng:click="action"></button>
```

and a bit of JavaScript

```
.directive('uiConfirm', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.bind('click.confirm', function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Now, what I'm trying to do, is to cancel the ng:click event, from within the directive.
But the ng:click still get's triggered, no matter what I do.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dbbzy/2/)

Edit:
By the way, causing an error within the this scope:

```
element.bind('click.confirm', function(event)
{
    causeAnError();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Does the trick, and canceles the event propagation, but also throws and ugly error =)

Edit 2:
Finally I've found a solution!

```
.directive('uiConfirm', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.bind('click', function(event)
            {
                scope.$eval(attrs.uiConfirm); // this line of code does the magic!
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Edit 3:

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
.directive('uiConfirm', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            /**
             * Clicking the trigger start the confirmation process.
             */
            element.bind('click.confirm', function(event)
            {
                // not confirmed?
                if( ! element.data().confirmed)
                {
                    element.data().confirmed = true;
                    element.addClass('btn-danger');
                }
                // is already confirmed..
                else
                {
                    element.trigger('mouseout.confirm');
                    scope.$eval(attrs.uiConfirm);
                }
            });

            /**
             * Leaving the element, resets the whole process.
             */
            element.bind('mouseout.confirm', function()
            {
                // reset all values
                element.data().confirmed = false;
                element.removeClass('btn-danger');
            });

            // reset the whole process on the first run
            element.trigger('mouseout.confirm');
        }
    }
})
```

Clicking a button the first time, gonna make it red, and doesn't trigger any action. Clicking a second time, calls the action. Leaving the button resets the whole process.

Comment: @Arun P Johny - thank you for the Fiddle!!

Comment: what you are trying to do may be related to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/ADylKzNT5oI/n6ZagosZZgsJ

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've already seen this, but it's another scenario.

Comment: What does `bind('click.confirm')` do?  I haven't seen that before.

Comment: click = event, confirm = namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments on @Flek's answer, to call a function defined in an attribute,

```
ui:confirm="action()"
```

use [scope.$eval()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24eval):

```
element.bind('click', function(event) {
    scope.$eval(attrs.uiConfirm);  // calls action() on the scope
});
```

Comment: As of Angular 1.2.0-rc.3 and probably earlier, you should use `scope.$apply()` instead so that any actions that effect the scope will show up...

Comment: im using angular 1.3.15 and it doesnt stop ng-click from executing.

Answer (score 1):

You have two nested directives:

1. uiConfirm
2. ngClick

You then bind two event handlers to it (one by uiConfirm and the other one by ngClick).
With **preventDefault** you want to stop the default action but I guess the default action of a button is not calling the action() method.
**stopPropagation** just prevents the event from *bubbling* up the DOM tree but since you only care about the button itself it doesn't change anything.

What I would do is to create a custom action method within the directive and then check whether it should do something or not.

```
.directive('uiConfirm', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.action = function(){
                // Check whether there is something to do or not.
            };
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Let's assume, instead of the ng:click, I create ui:confirm that will be a mix of ng:click and previous ui:confirm. But how can I evaluate the function that I've passed into the directive, from within the directive? ui:confirm="action()" -> in the directive it's a simple string, not a function.

Comment: @maximkott, `scope.$eval(attrs.uiConfirm)`.

Comment: @MarkRajcok gonna try this, post you the result later)

Comment: @MarkRajcok Dude, this did the trick! post a real answer so I can give you an "accept", Cheers!))

Comment: This solution feels much better than the accepted answer.